# Quick way around JQuery's .remove() leaving whitespace in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery's .append() and .remove() functions to add and remove variables from a div.

So the div looks a little like this when things are inside:

```
<div id="list">
    <a>var1</a>
    <a>var2</a>
    <a>var3</a>
</div>
```

The problem is when I use .remove() on something in the div, it leaves a space in the DOM. So it looks like this:

```
var1

var3
```

I understand why this is happening but is there a simple way to solve this with another JQuery function that might make the div output like this after I use .remove():

```
var1
var3
```

Or do I neeed to do something more complicated?

Comment: What do you mean "in the DOM"? Like, in the source viewer, or you are  seeing whitespace in your rendered page? Can you show a demo of this happening? I have never heard of this.

Comment: jquery isn't leaving the space. What's left is the newline character because all jQuery cares about is the element itself. One option would be to select the child elements, detach them, empty the div, then append them back to the div. Doing so will of course lose ALL of the new line characters though, not just the extra one.

Comment: Could you post [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I do not see any space between links. http://jsfiddle.net/C6MT5/

Comment: Check that your CSS isn't defining extra margin or padding after/before those elements.

Comment: Are you sure each `a` element isn't wrapped in another element?

Comment: I have the div empty when the page loads. Then I have a button that adds a variable to the list. And when its clicked it turns into a button that removes that variable from the list. When I remove the variable, the whitespace is left behind on my rendered page.

Comment: @AzzyDude Show us your code. Currently this is way too open-ended.

Comment: "I have a button that adds a variable to the list" - You mean it adds an element to the list? And what turns into a button? You haven't shown us that. Maybe that is getting left behind?

Comment: @AzzyDude You're getting whitespace, because your var is only the content of your anchor tags. When you remove the var, you leave an empty anchor on the page which is creating white space. The fiddle posted by 'Learner' is targeting the anchors directly, which is why his fiddle shows no whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your element is actually surrounded in text nodes containing a newline, as it's what your html says. If you don't believe me: http://tinker.io/7f667/1

```
\n<a>var1</a>\n<a>var2</a>\n<a>var3</a>\n
```

You don't notice them in display because html isn't (usually) whitespace sensitive.

If you want to remove the surrounding newlines, then tell the DOM to remove them: http://tinker.io/7f667/2

```
//assuming `list` is your container, and `toRemove` is the element to be removed
list.removeChild(toRemove.previousSibling);
list.removeChild(toRemove.nextSibling);
list.removeChild(toRemove);
```

Should be trivial to turn that into jquery code if you choose. Just pay attention that the surrounding text nodes are *not* elements.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to insert parent() in there to remove the parent container rather than only removing the variable.

So if your code was like this:

```
$(myVar).remove();
```

... change it to this:

```
$(myVar).parent().remove();
```

Something else you could do if you need to preserve the existance of that particular parent container (like you may be adding something back into it) is to append a class to the parent that hides the container (and consequently the variable you want to remove) but can be repopulated and made visible again later.

```
.deactivated { display:none; }

$(myVar).parent().addClass('deactivated');
```

... then later you could do this:

```
$(myVar).parent().html(newValue).removeClass('deactivated');
```

Having written all that, you should REALLY probably cache the parent itself as a separate variable.. but you get the idea.

Comment: Either I did not understand the question well or your answer is too much for what's been asked. :D

Comment: Why would he want to remove the parent to hide var2 but not hide var1 or 3? this makes no sense..

Comment: @KevinB The "parent" in his case are the anchor tags. The variable he's removing is only the contents of the anchor tags, so he's getting blank spaces because he's leaving empty anchor tags in the markup. Targeting parent targets the anchors rather than just the contents of the anchors, allowing the page to flow the way he said he'd like it to flow.

Comment: @Learner Why is it "too much"? I gave him two options, both exceptionally simple.

Comment: Are you suggesting he's doing $("div a").contents()? otherwise, no, he would not be acting on the text nodes, he'd be acting on the anchor elements.

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific as to what I'm doing: I have the div empty when the page loads. Then I have a button that adds a variable to the list. And when its clicked it turns into a button that removes that variable from the list. When I remove the variable, the whitespace is left behind on my rendered page.

Comment: @AzzyDude I'm almost certain that I'm right, that the variables you're executing a remove command against only represent the content of your buttons, and not the anchor tags. But you really should post more code to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Azzy: it's better if you post your jQuery code here in the question or on jsfiddle so that everyone knows what your are trying to do instead of answering you based on assumptions.

Comment: relic: it's too much because it's based on assumption. That's why I asked Azzy to post complete code. Nothing really to do with your approach or solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="list">
    <a>var1</a>
    <a>var2</a>
    <a>var3</a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var var_to_remove = "var2";
//the anchor with var2 should be removed
$("#list > a").each(function()
{
  if($(this).text() == var_to_remove)
  {
    $(this).detach();
  }
});
</script>
```

You would obviously probably want to change the jquery to make the var_to_remove not hard-coded..and I'm assuming you want it to be on a click handler or something but this is another way to do it...